# MongoDB Atlas read performance

Tags: mongodb, atlas

EDIT: That was a red herring - see answer below.

We have a set of databases on MongoDB Atlas (M10, M20 clusters), and I noticed that while planning and executing queries is super fast, actually *returning* bigger sets of documents takes ages.

As an example, the query below fetches 30K IDs from a collection (which contains just 100K documents). This takes 15 seconds to return that data from an M20 cluster (either to a co-located node app, or to my local machine):

```
db.mycollection.find({}, {_id: 1}).limit(30000)
```

In comparison: my toy PostgreSQL instance that costs a fraction of the M20 cluster (also located in the same AWS location) needs 0.5 seconds to return me 100K full rows from a table with 10M rows.

I understand that MongoDb has some overhead due to JSON, but that performance difference is so huge that I can't help but wonder whether that is really just the performance I can expect from a MongoDB, or whether something is severely off with those clusters?

Comment: Sounds pretty slow. How large is that result set in total, 12 bytes (size of ObjectIds) x 30,000 = 360kb? How are you timing the operation? Does the duration increase linearly with result set size? Do you see CPU steal in the metrics graphs for the cluster?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty linear. Size is higher (1.7MB because it's JSON with an `$oid` tag), CPU doesn't seem to be an issue (which would explain the similar performance across different cluster sizes). I'm currently simply timing it from the response time in my database client - it's so slow that I don't need more accurate results, unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a huge red herring :/

- After running the query on our production application, some post-processing runs. It turns out this added a huge overhead in case of this big a result.
- Every time I executed the naked query on my local DB client, it took pretty much the same time (minus a little bit of time I attributed to the missing post-processing). But what's probably happening is that this client applies very small batch sizes when retrieving the data, or even `limit`s the results behind the scene, as it shows the data in pages. So completely different reason that lead to the same delay, which sent me on a wild goose chase :)

Silver lining: Not relying on default batch sizes made a huge difference here. Explicitly setting the batch size to 5K or 10K go me an easy 30% performance boost, also when triggering the queries through the Node client library.